# Loading JSON files via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have over 100 JSON files which is nested and I am trying to Load the JSON files via Data FactoryV2 into SQL Data Warehouse. I have created the Data FactoryV2 and everything seems fine the connection below seems fine and the Data Preview seems fine also.

[image]

When I run the Data Factory I get this error:

[image]

I am not sure what the issue is. I have tried to re-create the Data Factory several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear enough when it says "All columns of the table must be specified...". This means that the table in the data warehouse has more columns than what you are seeing in the preview of the json file. You will need to create a table in the data warehouse with the same columns that are shown in the preview of the json files.

If you need to insert them in a table with more fields, create a "staging" table with the same columns as the json file, and then call a stored procedure to insert the content of this staging table in the corresponding table.

Hope this helped!